# The limit of the difference quotients

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ is defined in $(-1,1)$ and $f'(0)$ exists. Suppose $-1<\alpha_n<\beta_n<1$, $\alpha_n\to 0$, and $\beta_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Define the difference quotients $D_n=\dfrac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}$. If $f'$ is continuous in $(-1,1),$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}D_n=f'(0)$

Give an example in which $f$ is diffenrentiable in $(-1,1)$ (but $f'$ is not continuous at $0$) and in which $\alpha_n, \beta_n$ tend to $0$ in a such way that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}D_n$ exists but it's different from $f'(0)$.

**Proof:** So $f'\in C(-1,1)$ then $f$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$. For any pairs of $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ we apply Mean Value Theorem and we get $f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)=(\beta_n-\alpha_n)f'(\theta_n)$ where $\alpha_n<\theta_n<\beta_n$. If $n\to \infty$ then $\lim D_n=\lim \dfrac{f(\beta_n)-f(\alpha_n)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}=\lim f'(\theta_n)=f'(0)$ because $\theta_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and $f'$ is continuous at zero.

Let's take a look at function $f(x)=x^2\sin \dfrac{1}{x} (x\neq 0)$ and $f(0)=0$
and it's easy to check that $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. In this case we have$$D_n=\dfrac{\beta_n^2\sin \dfrac{1}{\beta_n}-\alpha_n^2\sin \dfrac{1}{\alpha_n}}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}.$$ How to choose sequences $\beta_n, \alpha_n$ such that $\beta_n, \alpha_n\to 0$ with $D_n\to d\neq 0$?

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ with $\sin(1/\beta_n)=1$ and $\sin(1/\alpha_n)=-1$:
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha_n}=\frac{3\,\pi}{2}+2\,\pi\,n,\quad\frac{1}{\beta}=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\,\pi\,n.
$$